# Grep on docker image names in package.json

Tags: bash, docker, grep, docker-compose, package.json

I want to set a script in the package.json that starts the container based on image-name that I grep after piping the docker images command, something like this:

```
"docker:run": "docker run -it -v /$(pwd):/app $(docker images | grep 'online-check-in-frontend' | awk '{ print $1 }') sh",
```

also tried :

```
"docker:run": "docker run -it -v /$(pwd):/app $(docker images | grep \"online-check-in-frontend\" | awk \"{ print $1 }\") sh",
```

The commands above is not working, i get the following error:
[image]

Im using windows, and bash. :S

Br

Comment: what about single quotes instead of double quotes in awk command?

Comment: Same fault, and lint is complaining since its not a valid escape character

Comment: It helps if you first echo your statement to check what's it is trying to execute. `"docker:run": "echo docker run -it -v /$(pwd):/app $(docker images | grep 'online-check-in-frontend' | awk '{ print $1 }') sh"`

Comment: `root@RHTDFLOW201:~# echo docker run -it -v /$(pwd):/app $(docker images | grep 'grafana/grafana' | awk '{ print $1 }') sh` will result in: 
`docker run -it -v //root:/app grafana/grafana sh`

Comment: Also, for the volume mapping you don't seem to need the additional "/". Trying this actually seems to generate a valid docker run command: `docker run -it -v $(pwd):/app $(docker images | grep 'grafana/grafana' | awk '{ print $1 }') sh`